# mongoose giving error in contactSchema.virtual().set()

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Giving me error on `trim() and split()` at the bottom of code when I try to save.

**ERROR**

```
    {"error":{"message":"Object #<Object> has no 
method 'trim'","stack":"TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'trim'\n    
at model.<anonymous> ...}}
```

**Model**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , Schema = mongoose.Schema
    , ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var ContactSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        first: String,
        last: String,
        clean: {type: String, unique: true}
    },
    email: String,
    added: Date
});

ContactSchema
    .index({name: {last: 1, clean: 1}, email: 1})
    .pre('save', function (next) {
        if (!this.added) this.added = new Date();
        this.name.clean = (this.name.first + '-' + this.name.last).toLowerCase();
        next();
    })
    .virtual('name.full').get(function () {
        return this.name.first + ' ' + this.name.last;
    })
    .set(function (name) {
        var split = name.trim().split(' ');
        this.name.first = split[0];
        this.name.last = split[1];
        this.name.clean = split.join('-').toLowerCase();
    });



exports.contactModel = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema, 'Contact');
```

**UPDATE**

```
req.body.name passed which contains object {first:'s', last:'d'}

app.post('/api/contact', function (req, res, next) {
    new Contact({
        name: {
            full: req.body.name 
        },
        email: req.body.email
    }).save(function (err, docs) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            res.send(docs);
        });
});
```

Comment: What version of mongoose do you have installed? I'm using an implementation of `name.full` very close to this and it works.

Comment: It says you're calling .trim on an object and not a string. Are you sure you're setting name.full with a string?

Comment: @gustavohenke, using latest version

Comment: @andreas-hultgren, I have updated and added more code at the bottom. Please see question.

Comment: So the problem is right there, you get an object, you can neither split nor trim it. If you get a string such as "a d" it can be split into first and last, but if it's already an object you can simply get name.first or name.last.

Comment: @andreas-hultgren, Example I am following is passing req.body.name and its working fine for him but not me instead I need to req.body.name.first + ' ' + req.body.name.last to make it work.

Comment: In that case the example must receive the full name as a string, or it can't work

Comment: To elaborate on @AndreasHultgren answer, it's because name.full is in the schema, so you can not create a virtual with the same name.

Comment: you must send pass name object as string from front-end , Then you can use  `req.body.name` and set it to `name.full`